# Changing soap action URI based on environment

Tags: c#, web-services

The code I wrote is integrating with 3rd party web service. The problem is that soap actions for service differs in test and production environments and albeit this URIs are non-important, host returns 400 - bad request error, if soap action URI is wrong.
Host service is written in Java. We are using C# web service proxy.

Reference.cs

```
/// <remarks/>
        [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://1.1.1.1:9080/wss/Ping", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
        [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PingResp", Namespace="http://namespace/data")]
        public PingResp Ping([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PingReq", Namespace="http://namespace/data")] PingReq PingReq) {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("Ping", new object[] {
                        PingReq});
            return ((PingResp)(results[0]));
        }
```

For production environment, SoapAction is:

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://2.2.2.2:9080/wss/Ping", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
```

Is there a way to make this dynamic i.e. is it possible to change soap action URI based on config setting?

I have tried extending `SoapDocumentMethodAttribute` class, but it is sealed.

Answer (score 2):

Since it needs a compile time constant, we have to set this value before compiling so having it based on environment and using something like `ConfigurationManager` is not possible.

You could make a global static class with const properties that get populated via `#if` preprocessors and specify your conditional compilation symbols at build.

```
   public static class GlobalConstants
    {
#if DEBUG
        public const string Uri = "devUri";
#endif
#if TEST
        public const string Uri = "testUri";
#endif
#if RELEASE
        public const string Uri = "releaseUri";
#endif

    }
```

And you could use it like

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute(GlobalConstants.Uri, Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
```

This does add complexity when migrating to new environments, but it is a way to get something close to what you are looking for.

Some docs on specifying compilation symbols at build: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx